# bottle dynamic route not working, always got 404

Tags: python, bottle

I have an issue with one of my route in Bottle. The following route give me a 404 (http://127.0.0.1:8666/user/1) :

```
import bottle

app = application = bottle.Bottle()
@login_required
@app.route('/user/<userid:int>', method='GET')

def user_member(userid):

    member = user.member(userid)
    if not len(member):
        bottle.abort(404)

    return bottle.jinja2_template('user', member=member)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bottle.debug(True)
    bottle.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8666, thread_count=5, reloader=True)
```

All others route is working just fine. Here is the page output :

```
Error: 404 Not Found

Sorry, the requested URL 'http://127.0.0.1:8666/user/1' caused an error:

Unknown Error.
```

In fact my function is never when using the previous URL.

*So I comment most part of the code in the file and I found the mistake. It comes from the static route function. The route for static confuse bottle when using dynamic route.*

Comment: I think the issue is caused by `member = user.member(userid)` and not the route per se. Try accessing the user model without the route. E.g. simply add `print user.member(1)` after `app = application = bottle.Bottle()` and use the terminal output to debug further.

Comment: so I tried `print user.member(1)` just after `app = application = bottle.Bottle` and it works fine. The request get executed and I can see the results.

Comment: OK. Your code works fine for me when I take out the `@login_required` decorator and replace everything in `def user_member(userid)` with  `return userid`. Maybe `member` doesn't have a length so `len(members)` fails or maybe the `@login_required` decorator is to blame. Try commenting out various lines until everything works to narrow down the issue. Adding the terminal output to your question would also be helpful.

Comment: hmmm...So I comment everything and even `@login_required` I let only `return bottle.jinja2_template('user', member={})` and I've still an error 404.

Comment: I have this issue only with dynamic routing.

Comment: Your code will not work as posted.  What is `login_required`?  You haven't shown the code for that or where you import it from.

Comment: Also, what is `user`?

Comment: Oh sorry, `@login_required` check if the user is logged and `user` is a class for SQL request. But both works as I use them for others route (static).

Comment: Oh sorry, `@login_required` check if the user is logged and `user` is a class for SQL request. But both works as I use them for others route (static). And I comment that part so I don't think there is a problem with these code. Also, I have the issue even if do only `return "hello"` in that function. So, it seems to be a real 404 issue but trigger by what ? Is it possible to trace what's going on in Bottle when typing "http://127.0.0.1:8666/user/1" ?

Comment: @sesshoumaru I also faced the same issue as you. You should post your findings as answer and mark it as correct. Also managed to find the responsible route by commenting out in turn. "It comes from the static route function. The route for static confuse bottle when using dynamic route."